# How to use useCallback, useMemo and React.memo when dependency is an object?

Tags: reactjs, memoization, usecallback, react-usememo, react-memo

I have `useMemo` when one of its dependencies is an `Object` that I get from the server, so even when the content of the object is the same - the `useMemo` is called over and over again in each sync from the server because the object itself is different every time, of course it is the same for `useCallback` and `React.memo`.

How can I solve this?

I was thinking about checking manually if the new result has the same contents as the previous result and if it does - stay with the previous object reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options really:

- do as you planned, i.e. don't change the object if it's deep-equal (e.g. [`deep-equal` on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal)) to the object you receive:

  ```
  const [obj, setObj] = React.useState();
  // ...
  const newObj = await getObjectFromServer();
  // Using the function form of setState to avoid races and an extra
  // dependency on `obj`:
  setObj(oldObj => equal(newObj, oldObj) ? oldObj : newObj);
  ```
- depend on the fields the `memo` uses, not the full object:

  - Not this:

    ```
    React.useMemo(() => obj.foo + 8, [obj]);
    ```
  - But this:

    ```
    React.useMemo(() => obj.foo + 8, [obj.foo]);
    ```

  However, that may easily get cumbersome and won't help if `obj.foo` itself is not a primitive.